# SwiftUI: How do I make a button open a URL in safari?

Tags: swift, url, button, swiftui

I want a button inside my app, that will open safari and a specific URL address. How do I do this? UIApplication.sharedApplication doesn't seem to work in SwiftUI.

This is my first question here. Please give feedback if I did something wrong

Comment: what are you getting in your console for `UIApplication.shared.open(url`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### iOS 14.0+

Using [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link):

```
Link("Some label", destination: URL(string: "https://www.mylink.com")!)
```

### Older versions

```
Button(action: {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.mylink.com") {
       UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
}) {
    Text("Some label")
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify: iOS<13 and iOS>14. Do you mean iOS≦13 ?

Comment: Worked like a charm for iOS 13 and 14. Thanks man!

Comment: Doesn't work in swiftui preview. Any idea why?

Comment: https://medium.com/@yunchingtan/swiftui-how-to-create-an-asynchronous-link-preview-9b5c4db57194

Answer (score 7):

In the View:

```
@Environment(\.openURL) private var openURL
```

Later, e.g. on button press:

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
openURL(url)
```

Read more: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a SceneDelegate you can handle URL addresses using the following:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {

    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }

    //Handle URL here
}
```

From there you can call openURL like you normally would:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, how to trigger that SceneDelegate method from view button or view model function?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through SwiftUI's `Link`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link.

Comment: Only if you are using iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, you can use [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link). For example:

`Link("Link Text", destination: URL(string: "https://www.example.com/page.html")!)`

Comment: Only if you are using iOS 14.