# Open non-URL string in Safari (e.g. Search)

Tags: swift, url, swiftui, safari, openurl

It's quite easy to open a `URL` in SwiftUI, e.g. as I've mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71677342/3667264), however, I'm interested in opening the following strings in the web browser (e.g. Safari) with the default search engine:

> samplestring

> 8883notaurl

Is there an option to open the query in a default search engine, instead of just composing a URL like this:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=query

And then opening it as a regular URL?

Comment: Try with `x-web-search://?[SearchValue]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x-web-search://` scheme with `x-web-search://?[SearchValue]`.

Sample code:

```
let urlStr = "x-web-search://?[SearchValue]"
if let url = URL(string: urlStr) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { didEnd in
            print("Did End: \(didEnd)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Can't open URL")
    }
} else {
    print("Isn't URL")
}
```